# Parsing binary data into ctypes Structure object via readinto()

Tags: python, c, data-structures, ctypes

I'm trying to handle a binary format, following the example here:

http://dabeaz.blogspot.jp/2009/08/python-binary-io-handling.html

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class Point(Structure):
>>>     _fields_ = [ ('x',c_double), ('y',c_double), ('z',c_double) ]
>>>
>>> g = open("foo","rb") # point structure data
>>> q = Point()
>>> g.readinto(q)
24
>>> q.x
2.0
```

I've defined a Structure of my header and I'm trying to read data into my structure, but I'm having some difficulty.
My structure is like this:

```
class BinaryHeader(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("sequence_number_4bytes", c_uint),
                ("ascii_text_32bytes", c_char),
                ("timestamp_4bytes", c_uint),
                ("more_funky_numbers_7bytes", c_uint, 56),
                ("some_flags_1byte", c_byte),
                ("other_flags_1byte", c_byte),
                ("payload_length_2bytes", c_ushort),

                ]
```

The [ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._fields_) says:

> For integer type fields like c_int, a third optional item can be
>   given. It must be a small positive integer defining the bit width of
>   the field.

So for `("more_funky_numbers_7bytes", c_uint, 56),` I've tried to define the field as a 7 byte field, but I'm getting the error:

> ValueError: number of bits invalid for bit field

So my first problem, is how can I define a 7 byte int field?

Then If I skip that problem and comment out the "more_funky_numbers_7bytes" field, the resulting data get's loaded in.. but as expected only 1 character is loaded into "ascii_text_32bytes".  And for some reason returns `16` which I assume is the calculated number of bytes it read into the structure... but If I'm commenting out my "funky number" field and ""ascii_text_32bytes" is only giving one char (1 byte), shouldn't that be 13, not 16???

Then I tried breaking out the char field into a separate structure, and reference that from within my Header structure. But that's not working either...

```
class StupidStaticCharField(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("ascii_text_1", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_2", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_3", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_4", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_5", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_6", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_7", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_8", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_9", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_10", c_byte),
                ("ascii_text_11", c_byte),
                .
                .
                .
                ]

class BinaryHeader(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("sequence_number_4bytes", c_uint),
                ("ascii_text_32bytes", StupidStaticCharField),
                ("timestamp_4bytes", c_uint),
                #("more_funky_numbers_7bytes", c_uint, 56),
                ("some_flags_1byte", c_ushort),
                ("other_flags_1byte", c_ushort),
                ("payload_length_2bytes", c_ushort),

                ]
```

So, any ideas how to:

1. Define a 7 byte field (which I'll need to decode using a defined function)
2. Define a static char field of 32 bytes

**UPDATE**

I've found a structure that seems to work...

```
class BinaryHeader(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("sequence_number_4bytes", c_uint),
                ("ascii_text_32bytes", c_char * 32),
                ("timestamp_4bytes", c_uint),
                ("more_funky_numbers_7bytes", c_byte * 7),
                ("some_flags_1byte", c_byte),
                ("other_flags_1byte", c_byte),
                ("payload_length_2bytes", c_ushort),

                ]
```

Now, however, my remaining question is, why when use [`.readinto()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.readinto):

```
f = open(binaryfile, "rb")

mystruct = BinaryHeader()
f.readinto(mystruct)
```

It's returning `52` and not the expected, `51`.  Where is that extra byte coming from, and where does it go?

**UPDATE 2**
For those interested here's an [example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#examples) of an alternative `struct` method to read values into a namedtuple mentioned by eryksun:

```
>>> record = 'raymond   \x32\x12\x08\x01\x08'
>>> name, serialnum, school, gradelevel = unpack('<10sHHb', record)

>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name serialnum school gradelevel')
>>> Student._make(unpack('<10sHHb', record))
Student(name='raymond   ', serialnum=4658, school=264, gradelevel=8)
```

Comment: If you look in your binaryfile  with some Hex Editor, do you see 51 bytes? Also, what does `len(mystruct)` say?

Comment: Yes, the `binaryfile` is over 50KB.  `len(mystruct)` doesn't seem to work, but `sizeof(mystruct)` does return 52...

Comment: You can add `_pack_ = 1` to the definition, but consider using the `struct` module with a `namedtuple` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using pack.  I was trying to move away from struct, because I had trouble figuring out how to get 7 bytes.  I was pulling it out as `7s` converting it to a string, and then having to convert it back for the decoding process.  I was hoping this approach would be a bit cleaner/faster.

Comment: I don't see an example in the question, but if you want 7 (signed) bytes using `struct.unpack`, the format is `'7b'`.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try to do a comparison with the `ctypes` and `struct` methods to see what is best for my case.  The `ctypes.Structure` and the ability to easily read into it is what initially attracted me to the `ctypes` way.  I have a handful of records in the resulting payload for which I'll need to create similar structures.

Comment: You might want to use the mmap module to map a section of the file (i.e. a given offset & size) into the process address space. Then you can create an array of records using `(BinaryHeader * N).from_buffer(mapped_file)`. This skips using `readinto` in a loop.

Comment: well it turns out that pypy doesn't support ctypes very well, so I'm going back to use `struct`, which at least seems to allow me to unpack data properly based on the defined endian.  I've now written a replacement underlying BigEndianStructure so I can pretty much keep my many defined structures the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line definition is actually for defining a [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field):

```
...
("more_funky_numbers_7bytes", c_uint, 56),
...
```

which is wrong here. The size of a bitfield should be less than or equals the size of the type, so `c_uint` should be at most 32, one extra bit will raise the exception:

```
ValueError: number of bits invalid for bit field
```

Example of using the bitfield:

```
from ctypes import *

class MyStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        # c_uint8 is 8 bits length
        ('a', c_uint8, 4), # first 4 bits of `a`
        ('b', c_uint8, 2), # next 2 bits of `a`
        ('c', c_uint8, 2), # next 2 bits of `a`
        ('d', c_uint8, 2), # since we are beyond the size of `a`
                           # new byte will be create and `d` will
                           # have the first two bits
    ]

mystruct = MyStructure()

mystruct.a = 0b0000
mystruct.b = 0b11
mystruct.c = 0b00
mystruct.d = 0b11

v = c_uint16()

# copy `mystruct` into `v`, I use Windows
cdll.msvcrt.memcpy(byref(v), byref(mystruct), sizeof(v))

print sizeof(mystruct) # 2 bytes, so 6 bits are left floating, you may
                       # want to memset with zeros
print bin(v.value)     # 0b1100110000
```

what you need is 7 bytes so what you endup doing is correct:

```
...
("more_funky_numbers_7bytes", c_byte * 7),
...
```

As for the size for the structure, It's going to be 52, I extra byte will be padded to [align the structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) on 4 bytes on 32 bit processor or 8 bytes on 64 bits. Here:

```
from ctypes import *

class BinaryHeader(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("sequence_number_4bytes", c_uint),
        ("ascii_text_32bytes", c_char * 32),
        ("timestamp_4bytes", c_uint),
        ("more_funky_numbers_7bytes", c_byte * 7),
        ("some_flags_1byte", c_byte),
        ("other_flags_1byte", c_byte),
        ("payload_length_2bytes", c_ushort),
    ]

mystruct = BinaryHeader(
    0x11111111,
    '\x22' * 32,
    0x33333333,
    (c_byte * 7)(*([0x44] * 7)),
    0x55,
    0x66,
    0x7777
)

print sizeof(mystruct)

with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(mystruct)
```

The extra byte is padded between `other_flags_1byte` and `payload_length_2bytes` in the file:

```
00000000 11 11 11 11 ....
00000004 22 22 22 22 """"
00000008 22 22 22 22 """"
0000000C 22 22 22 22 """"
00000010 22 22 22 22 """"
00000014 22 22 22 22 """"
00000018 22 22 22 22 """"
0000001C 22 22 22 22 """"
00000020 22 22 22 22 """"
00000024 33 33 33 33 3333
00000028 44 44 44 44 DDDD
0000002C 44 44 44 55 DDDU
00000030 66 00 77 77 f.ww
            ^
         extra byte
```

This is an issue when it comes to the file formats and network protocols. To change it pack it by 1:

```
 ...
class BinaryHeader(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("sequence_number_4bytes", c_uint),
...
```

the file will be:

```
00000000 11 11 11 11 ....
00000004 22 22 22 22 """"
00000008 22 22 22 22 """"
0000000C 22 22 22 22 """"
00000010 22 22 22 22 """"
00000014 22 22 22 22 """"
00000018 22 22 22 22 """"
0000001C 22 22 22 22 """"
00000020 22 22 22 22 """"
00000024 33 33 33 33 3333
00000028 44 44 44 44 DDDD
0000002C 44 44 44 55 DDDU
00000030 66 77 77    fww
```

As for `struct`, it won't make it easier in your case. Sadly it doesn't support nested tuples in the format. For example here:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>>
>>> data = '\x11\x11\x11\x11\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22
\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x22\x33
\x33\x33\x33\x44\x44\x44\x44\x44\x44\x44\x55\x66\x77\x77'
>>>
>>> BinaryHeader = Struct('>I32cI7BBBH')
>>>
>>> BinaryHeader.unpack(data)
(286331153, '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"'
, '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"'
, '"', '"', 858993459, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 85, 102, 30583)
>>>
```

This result cannot be used `namedtuple`, you still have parse it based on the index. It would work if you can do something like `'>I(32c)(I)(7B)(B)(B)H'`. This feature has been requested here [(Extend struct.unpack to produce nested tuples)](http://bugs.python.org/issue847857) since 2003 but nothing is done since.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!  You also managed to answer my unanswered question of "how do I handle 2 fields of 4 bits each?".  So  the ctypes method is progressing well.  I got stuck with `struct` trying to figure out how to handle the 4 bits case.

Comment: @monkut I believe `struct` doesn't support this, all what it suppors are the basic data types. You have to use [bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and do it manually.

Comment: Thanks again, I implemented it and it was roughly a 60% improvement over my previous sloppy code.  The only problem is when I went to try to read from tar files...apparently ExFileObject (file objects returned by tarinfo) don't support `.readinto(b)`, doh!