# Add .readinto(b) method to tarfile's ExFileObject?

Tags: python, ctypes, tarfile

So I'm trying to iterate over a number of files in a tar, and then load that data into some [ctype structures's I've defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536182/parsing-binary-data-into-ctypes-structure-object-via-readinto).  Which was working fine with non-tar files, but then I found out that the [ExFileObject](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/tarfile.py#l781) returned by tarfile's `extractfile(member)` method doesn't support the `.readinto(b)` method.

So right now here's what I'm doing:

```
import os
import tarfile
import io
from ctypes import c_uint, c_char, c_ubyte, c_ushort, BigEndianStructure

class MyStructure(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = True
    _fields_ = [
                ("id", c_uint), # 4 bytes
                ("namefield", c_char * 32), # 32 bytes
                ("timestamp", c_ubyte * 4), # 4 bytes
                ("payload_length", c_ushort), # 2 bytes
                ]  


def process_tar(tar_files):
    """
    untar and return file objects to be parsed
    """
    for filepath in tar_files:
        f = os.path.abspath(filepath)
        with tarfile.open(f, 'r:*') as tar_f:
            #tar_f.fileobject = io.BufferedReader
            for tarinfo_member in tar_f.getmembers():
                if tarinfo_member.isfile():
                    yield tar_f.extractfile(tarinfo_member)

f = "somefiles.tar.gz"                
for tar_member_fileobj in process_tar([f]):
    mystruct = MyStructure()
    tar_member_fileobj.readinto(mystruct)
```

And getting this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-4-257ee4b46c31> in <module>()
     29 for tar_member_fileobj in process_tar([f]):
     30     mystruct = MyStructure()
---> 31     tar_member_fileobj.readinto(mystruct)

AttributeError: 'ExFileObject' object has no attribute 'readinto'
```

Is there a way that this method can be added to the ExFileObject? Or, is there another way to easily get my data loaded into my defined ctypes structures?  I noticed that in the `tarfile` object it appears you can set the `fileobject` to be used for returned tarinfo files, but just swapping in io.BufferedReader didn't seem to work.

(I tried reading the ExFileObject into StringIO, but it doesn't seem to have `readinto()` implemented properly either...  I'm thinking I could just `extractall()` to a filespace in memory and re-open the files as standard file objects, but I'd like to avoid that since I would then have additional configuration needed)

Comment: How about replacing the call to `readinto` with `memmove(byref(mystruct), tar_member_fileobj.read(sizeof(mystruct)), sizeof(mystruct))`, shouldn't it do it? http://codepad.org/L0PZY1c3

Comment: can you put that as an answer?  I don't quite see how that works. oh its a single call to `memmove()`?

Comment: It should copy the header of the tar file's content into `mystruct`, I guess that what you are trying to do with `readinto`?

Comment: Yup, that works! go ahead and post the answer if you want the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExFileObject` doesn't profited `readinto` method, but you still can do it by reading the header form the file using `read` and copy the data into the structure using `memmove`:

```
memmove(byref(mystruct),
        tar_member_fileobj.read(sizeof(mystruct)),
        sizeof(mystruct)
)
```

For example:

```
import os
import tarfile
import io
from ctypes import *

class MyStructure(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = True
    _fields_ = [
                ("id", c_uint), # 4 bytes
                ("namefield", c_char * 32), # 32 bytes
                ("timestamp", c_ubyte * 4), # 4 bytes
                ("payload_length", c_ushort), # 2 bytes
                ]  


def process_tar(tar_files):
    """
    untar and return file objects to be parsed
    """
    for filepath in tar_files:
        f = os.path.abspath(filepath)
        with tarfile.open(f, 'r:*') as tar_f:
            #tar_f.fileobject = io.BufferedReader
            for tarinfo_member in tar_f.getmembers():
                if tarinfo_member.isfile():
                    yield tar_f.extractfile(tarinfo_member)



# test tar.gz file
open('somefiles.tar.gz', 'wb').write(
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xad\x5c\x34\x52\x02\x00\x66\x6f\x6f\x2e\x74\
\x61\x72\x00\xed\xca\x49\x0a\x83\x40\x14\x04\xd0\x7f\x85\xdc\
\xa0\x43\x92\x6d\xf8\xdd\xa6\xed\x6d\xe6\xc9\x79\x1e\x76\x82\
\x0a\x82\x4b\xef\x8f\xf6\x42\xf0\x02\x6e\xe4\xbf\x4d\x41\x55\
\xb5\x5d\xdf\x9c\xeb\x6a\xa8\x60\x3d\x1c\x51\x29\xc5\x80\x69\
\xb8\xc8\x99\x14\x8c\x0b\xc1\x25\x4a\x53\x5c\x4c\x5d\x28\x9c\
\xfe\x08\x64\x6d\xbb\xc9\xed\xfe\x78\xbe\xde\x9f\xef\xef\x6f\
\xd9\x8e\xeb\xf9\x41\x18\xc5\x49\x9a\xe5\x45\xb9\xbf\x1e\x8e\
\x27\xd0\xbb\x61\x00\x21\x84\x90\x0d\x19\x01\xd4\xe8\x88\xcf\
\x00\x08\x00\x00'
)

f = "somefiles.tar.gz"                
for tar_member_fileobj in process_tar([f]):
    mystruct = MyStructure()

    memmove(byref(mystruct),
            tar_member_fileobj.read(sizeof(mystruct)),
            sizeof(mystruct)
    )

    print hex(mystruct.id)
    print mystruct.namefield
    print ''.join(map(chr, mystruct.timestamp))
    print hex(mystruct.payload_length)
```

the string `\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xad ...` is a tar.gz file contains:

```
\x11\x11\x11\x11ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%\x00ABCD33
```

after copying that data into `mystruct` it should print:

```
0x11111111L
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%
ABCD
0x3333
```

Comment: Not much better, but you can create the Structure from a copy of the buffer in one pass: `MyStructure.from_buffer_copy(tar_member_fileobj.read(sizeof(MyStructure)))`.